# meaning of MinSupport in traminer

Tags: r, traminer

I'm trying to analyse event of subsequences in TraMineR, but I really don't know what "support" and "minSupport" stand for!

I looked for the meaning, but I just found this sentences in details of **seqefsub** function.

> There are two usages of this function. The first is for searching subsequences satisfying a support
>   condition. By default, the support is counted per sequence and not per occurrence, i.e. when a se-
>   quence contains twice a same subsequence it is counted only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support is a basic concept in data mining. Here, the support of a subsequence is the number (or proportion) of sequences that contain the subsequence. We could also consider the number of time the subsequence occurs among the considered sequences and then there would be different ways of counting the number of occurrences when a same subsequence appears more than once in a same sequence.

In the `seqefsub` function of `TraMineR` you can control the counting method with the `constraint`argument that should be set using `seqeconstraint`. For the available counting methods, see the help page of this latter function and the references given therein.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As you suggested, I found a relatively good explanation here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning

Comment: Updated the response with info on how you can control the counting method in `TraMineR`